# UNITY (Android) NOT ASKING FOR PERMISSION

Tags: unity-game-engine

My app have some problem! 
My app have three Scene , One of them using ARCore(ARScene), another one using camera device(CamScene). Problem is if i don't run ARScene , CamScene also does not work( NOT ASKING FOR PERMISSION)!
I create new app only use camera device, and it work (it ask for permission when begin run app)

Comment: How do you load these scenes? what platforms are you targeting?Are you getting any error messages? We'll need some more information before we can really help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public IEnumerator LoadAsync(SceneType levelNum)
{
    yield return null;
    StartOperation(levelNum);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    while (DoneLoading() == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("In while");
    }
    if (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Additive)
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(currentScene.name);
    else
        operation.allowSceneActivation = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    //effect.Hiden();
}
 private bool DoneLoading()
{
    return (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Additive && operation.isDone) || (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Single && operation.progress >= 0.9f);
}

private void StartOperation(SceneType levelNum)
{
    operation = UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelNum.ToString(), loadSceneMode);
    operation.allowSceneActivation = false;
}
  public void LoadSceneAsync(SceneType sceneType)
{
    effect.Show();
    StartCoroutine(LoadAsync(sceneType));
}
```

This is my load scene, i build this app for android device, when i run with editor my app word normal, no error messages!!